# can't push git's tag to remote as maven release process

Tags: java, git, maven, jenkins, maven-release-plugin

I'm using maven release plugin in order to be able to use the jenkins' release plugin.  I'm using a multi module project running it on linux system (centos).
for that I've added the following plugins configuration to parent pom:

```
<plugin>
<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
     <version>2.5.3</version>
     <configuration>
        <tagNameFormat>v@{project.version}</tagNameFormat>
        <arguments>-Dmaven.test.skip=true -DskipTests -Dbatch=true</arguments>
        <tagBase>http://gitcore/user/app/tags</tagBase>
     </configuration>
</plugin>
```

also added to the top of this `pom.xml` theses lines:

```
<scm>
   <connection>scm:git:git@gitcore:user/app.git</connection>
  <developerConnection>scm:git:git@gitcore:user/app.git</developerConnection>
   <url>http://gitcore.company.local/</url>
</scm>
```

After that I run the following maven command: 
**mvn -B release:clean release:prepare release:perform**

The prepare passes successfully
also it pushes the promotion of the pom version and it's modules (sub project), to git origin.
it creates only local git tag with the correct version but didn't success to push to remote.
what I'm getting after running maven with -X is:

org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:2.5.3:prepare (default-cli) on project projectParent: Unable to tag SCM
Provider message:
The git-push command failed.
Command output:
Access denied.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.

And above those lines, I noticed the following which related to pushing the git tag:

```
[INFO] Executing: /bin/sh -c cd /home/mickey/App/ProjectParent && git push git@gitcore:user/app.git refs/heads/release_version_8_0:refs/heads/release_version_8_0
[INFO] Working directory: /home/mickey/App/ProjectParent
[INFO] Tagging release with the label v8.0.2...
[DEBUG] ScmTagPhase :: scmTagParameters remotingTag true
[DEBUG] ScmTagPhase :: scmTagParameters scmRevision null
[DEBUG] ScmTagPhase :: fileSet  basedir = /home/mickey/App; files = []
[INFO] Executing: /bin/sh -c cd /home/mickey/App && git tag -F /tmp/maven-scm-876857130.commit v8.0.2
[INFO] Working directory: /home/mickey/App
[INFO] Executing: /bin/sh -c cd /home/mickey/App && git push **git@gitcore:user** refs/tags/v8.0.2
[INFO] Working directory: /home/mickey/App
```

I tried to run the last push locally (**git push git@gitcore:user**) with the same error I got when running from maven, but after I added to the push command also the name of the file it worked.  I can't understand why it isn't running the whole command of git push with the entire tag path as I put in the pom.

Comment: I just noticed there is a different in the working directory when it comes to git tag.
Working directory: /home/mickey/App
instead of Working directory: /home/mickey/App/ProjectParent 
as attached in the logs.
is that make any scenes?

Comment: I think i got it.
i debugged the maven release plugin, and find out that with some weird reason before getting to the tagging step in git, the plugin tries to look in one folder upper to the current which its not a project at all.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problem, but I was using flat directory multi-module like:

```
release-workspace\
|
|--release-parent
|    |+pom.xml (modules: ../release-module1, ../release-module2)
|--release-module1
|    |+pom.xml (parent: ../release-parent/pom.xml)
|--release-module2
|    |+pom.xml (parent: ../release-parent/pom.xml)
```

The version 2.x doesn't support flat directory multi-module. You can check it out here https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MRELEASE-261

As a workaround, you can create a pom.xml in the root directory

```
release-workspace\
|
|--release-parent
|    |+pom.xml (parent: ../pom.xml, modules: ../release-module1, ../release-module2)
|--release-module1
|    |+pom.xml (parent: ../release-parent/pom.xml)
|--release-module2
|    |+pom.xml (parent: ../release-parent/pom.xml)
|--pom.xml (modules: release-parent) <-- maven-release-plugin goes
```